# Chat in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. In my project I use Laravel 5.8.

I would like to add a chat feature on my site (1 user: 1 user). Can you recommend any ready Laravel packages / components for this?

Comment: there is search in google, just type your request also there is github its like a storage for packages. Try it, its easy

Answer (score 3):

Build a chat app with Laravel, Vue.js and Pusher. Follow the tutorial https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel

[laravel pusher chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS19X.gif)

Clone the project repository by running the command below if you use SSH

```
git clone git@github.com:ammezie/laravel-chat.git
```

If you use https, use this instead

```
git clone https://github.com/ammezie/laravel-chat.git
```

After cloning,run:

```
composer install
```

Duplicate `.env.example` and rename it `.env`

Then run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

**Prerequisites**

**Setup Pusher**

If you don't have one already, create a free Pusher account at https://pusher.com/signup then login to your dashboard and create an app.

Set the `BROADCAST_DRIVER` in your `.env` file to pusher:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

Then fill in your Pusher app credentials in your `.env` file:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=
```

**Database Migrations**

Be sure to fill in your database details in your `.env` file before running the migrations:

php artisan migrate
And finally, start the application:

```
php artisan serve
```

and visit http://localhost:8000/ to see the application in action.

source : https://github.com/ammezie/laravel-chat